# How to bind views and view models that exist in different dlls using "Prism.Forms" in "Xamarin.Forms"?

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms, prism

I am using **"VS15"**, **'Prism.Forms 6.2.0'** for my **"Xamarin.Forms"** solution.

My views and view models exist in different dlls.

and it seems that

```
prism:ViewModelLocator.AutowireViewModel="True"
```

only works when views and view models are in the same dll.

What is the best prism approach of binding views to view models using in that case?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Either change the convention to fit your needs or use the `Container.RegisterTypeForNavigation<MainPage, MainPageViewModel>()` method.